# ImageView inside horizontal StackView is not respecting constraint height

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a horizontal `UIStackView`: on the left there's a `UIImageView` and on the right labels and buttons.

I hardcoded the imageview to be 60x60 (with constraints). However, because the right side needs a bit more vertical space, the total height of the stack becomes 84. Wanting to keep the image centered vertically, I set the imageview's `centerY` to equal its superview (the stack). In Interface Builder everything looks as it should.

When I run the app however, the imageview resizes itself to 60x84, completely disregarding the height constraint (or even the 1:1 aspect ratio constraint). I looked at the `Debug View Hierarchy` and I can see the constraints there, but they're greyed out.

I tried `.aspectFit` and even manually adding the height constraint at runtime but nothing changes. *Note: aspectFit centers the image and shows it as 60x60, but its frame is still 60x84*

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIStackView` arranges its subviews, based on the setting you give it.

If you tell the stack view to be 84-points tall, and you set its `alignment = .fill`, its subviews will be 84-points tall.

Couple options:

1 - set `.alignment = .center` ... for a horizontal stack view, that will center the views vertically. You can also use `.top` or `.bottom` depending on how you want the views to layout.

2 - embed the image view in a plain (clear) `UIView`, and constrain it vertically (top / centerY / bottom / as desired) in that view. Then, **that** view will stretch to 84-points tall, while your image view will retain its own height.

Comment: Thank you!! Setting the alignment to center fixed it. I even thought I tried it, but I *actually* changed `Content Mode` to Center, no the `Alignment`.